# SQL command text through ETW events for the SQL ETW event source

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, etw

Using the nice EtwStream library it is possible to listen to ETW events. However when listening to the SQL provider, the command text is not captured:

```
ObservableEventListener.FromTraceEvent(WellKnownEventSources.SqlEventSource).LogToConsole(ev => ev.ToString());
```

Any idea as to how to have this data emitted through ETW?

Answer (score 1):

This property filled only for stored procedures:

```cs
        private void WriteBeginExecuteEvent()
        {
            if (SqlEventSource.Log.IsEnabled() && Connection != null)
            {
                string commandText = CommandType == CommandType.StoredProcedure ? CommandText : string.Empty;
                SqlEventSource.Log.BeginExecute(GetHashCode(), Connection.DataSource, Connection.Database, commandText);
            }
        }
```

(source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs,cc46bed589639792)

You can only rewrite queries to stored procedures calls or write your own etw provider.